# How to create a rule that changes a cell based on its previous value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a rule such that if the cell value changes, it would change color based on its previous value. for example If it's previous value was less than its new value then i want it to change to blue else if he value is greater i want to change it to green. If its the same change it to orange. I guess i am trying to compare the cell to it's self rather than to another cell. Is this possible in excel?

I have tried to use the greater than formula on it's self but that did not work!

Comment: The old value is not kept anywhere by Excel, so it is impossible to make such a rule. Maybe you can write a macro, that sets the color hard at the moment of change, but afterwards, as the old value is gone, there is no way to calculate the color ever again, so it is necessarily a fixed setting of the color - otherwise, after save/load, how would Excel know how to color the cell? You might be able in the macro to copy the old value to somewhere else to keep it, not sure.

Comment: yea that is what i thought :( i thought someone would have a trick or two up their sleeves :p

Comment: I agree with the other comments and answer, this isn't possible with just a formula and without storing the old value somewhere else. However, using the `Worksheet_Change` event, you could write a macro that compares the old value (stored in a separate cell) to the new value, makes whatever changes you want to the cell, then copies the new value over the old value.

Comment: @blm, any idea if `Worksheet_Change` would fire if one edits a cell but does not actually change the value? (As for the *"If its the same change it to orange"*.)

Comment: It will fire. As long as you do a positive action it will fire (hit F2 and enter it will fire it, but changing a cell and hit ESC will not => negative action)

Comment: @Arjan It does. Add the macro `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Address & " changed"
End Sub
` (on three lines starting Private, MsgBox, and End) then edit a cell. Even if at the end of the edit it has the same value as before, the macro will fire and you'll get the MsgBox. It *doesn't* fire on things like style changes.

Comment: Does the cell in question have a *formula* or a *typed value* ??

Answer (score 4):

You could use an old trick to do exactly this without VBA:

First go to File -> Options -> Formulas -> Enable iterative calculation. This allows for "circular references", [formulas that refer to their own cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73a772d5-6224-407c-8029-60a47488b6aa):

> **Iteration** is the repeated recalculation of a worksheet until a specific numeric condition is met. Excel cannot automatically calculate a formula that refers to the cell — either directly or indirectly — that contains the formula. This is called a circular reference. If a formula refers back to one of its own cells, you must determine how many times the formula should recalculate. Circular references can iterate indefinitely. However, you can control the maximum number of iterations and the amount of acceptable change.

I assume A1 as your cell you want to do what you are looking for. B1 and C1 are helper-cells, which are calculated in order:

```
B1: =IF(A1<>C1,C1,B1)
C1: =IF(B1=C1,A1,C1)
```

Now whenever you change the value of cell A1, in B1 is the last value:

```
----> iterations when A1 is edited

A1:     1 |     2      2 |     3      3       3
B1: =B1=1 | =C1=1  =B1=1 | =C1=1  =B1=2   =B1=2
C1: =C1=1 | =A1=1  =C1=2 | =A1=2  =C1=2   =C1=3
```

Set your conditional formatting to compare A1 with B1 to get what you want (except for *"if it's the same change it to orange"*). The helper-cells can be hidden or be at different sheets... doesn't matter, as long as the order is not changed.

---

To do it in one cell you could use:

```
B1: =IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1))<>TEXT(A1,"@"),RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1))&" "&A1,B1),"0 "&A1)
```

to compare you need to use:

```
    =(LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))*1)>A1 (for new value is smaller)
    =(LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))*1)<A1 (for new value is bigger)
```

---

To do it the Long way, you could use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1)-11)<>TEXT(A1,"@"),MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1)-10)&A1&" "&TEXT(NOW()*72000,"0"),IF(AND(((NOW()*72000)-2)>(RIGHT(B1,10)*1),CELL("address")=CELL("address",A1)),A1&" "&A1&" "&TEXT(NOW()*72000,"0"),B1)),"0 "&A1&" "&TEXT(NOW()*72000,"0"))
```

Whenever the A1 is changed it will be tracked. It will also be tracked if a recalculation is fired while A1 is selected and the last recorded change is older than 2 seconds.
The conditional formatting stays the same (but now also goes for change to old value):

```
    =(LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))*1)>A1 (for new value is smaller)
    =(LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))*1)<A1 (for new value is bigger)
    =(LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))*1)=A1 (for new value is same)
```

---

Another way could be the "Shared Workbook" option. While track changes in a separate sheet. With a simple lookup you could go for the last change made in a specific cell (the event will tell the old value) which you could use as ref in conditional formatting.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I don't understand how the iterations work, or your edit of the iterations is wrong... If you say the formulas are evaluated in order, then if after setting A1=2, B1 gets to be C1 (at that point: 1) and then C1 gets to be A1, then why do you think at that point A1 is still 1, not its new value 2? (Same for the other changes...?)

Comment: *"C1 get that B1 is C1 and will change"*, yes, change into the value of A1, right? Agreed. But then why into *the old value* of A1...? Why would the `IF(...)` formulas use the new value in the comparison, and use the old value in the assignment? (All said, your solution surely works; I just think that in the iterations following each edit different things happen, and only two iterations are ever needed, not 3, even when starting with a better value for B1...)

Comment: Hehe, I very much agree with your comment, but I don't think the values in your answer follow that logic. But I also think all steps are shown, so somehow you and I interpret the diagram I added differently... For me the changes in the values read top to bottom, left to right :-)

Comment: @Arjan At least: I got the 1 cell version with tracking the "change to same" action :D

Comment: Nice. And of course feel free to remove the iterations that I added :-)

Comment: And Dirk's smarter than all of us. :-) Nice technique Dirk.

Answer (score 2):

The old value is not kept anywhere by Excel, so *it is impossible to make this as a rule.*

Maybe you can write a macro, that sets the color hard at the moment of change, but afterwards, as the old value is gone, there is no way to calculate the color ever again, so it is necessarily a fixed setting of the color - otherwise, after save/load, how would Excel know how to color the cell? You might be able in the macro to copy the old value to somewhere else to keep it, not sure.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong when I asked you to post your comment as an answer: it seems it's actually possible! See the new answer. (Although I did not test that.)